# SSIS process to archive production DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS, i got a task to archive the data from production to Archive DB and then delete the data from production keeping 13 months of data in production. There is around 300+ tables of these i have to archive around 50 tables. Out of these 50 table 6 tables have size around 1 TB.
Listing out the the 2 methods which we are planning.
1. Using 50 data flow tasks in a sequence container.
2. Using SELECT * FROM...INSERT INTO.. where table name and column name can be stored in some configuration table and through loop we can archive the data.

Which will be the better option?
Is there any other better method so please let me know.
What precautions(Performanec tips) i have to take while doing the archive process so that it should not affect the Production server?

Please give your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: You may wish to ask whether table partitioning is an option - then you don't have to archive. Personally if the databases are on the same server I would definitely take the second option. Are there any other constraints?

Comment: The DB's are not in same server...we thought of table partition but mostly these data are idle so we thought of archiving would be the best solution. There is another solution we have got by using Delete and OUTPUT clause, i think it will be better than select * INSERT INTO.

Comment: INSERT INTO / SELECT is only good if the db's are on the same server. There are any number of solutions you could use. If you are new to databases you might want to use SSIS as it uses a graphical interface

Comment: I like SSIS for this sort of thing. If your tables have a consistent design (i.e. they all have a column by the same name that you can rely on for determining what data is able to be archived), you can use BIML to create the SSIS package. But learn to walk before you run. That is, write the process for one table and then iterate on it to get them all.